# Getting request Accept-Header from Spring or Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

Spring Boot/Thymeleaf here. Trying to get internationalization working with my email templates and running into a snafu.

In my configuration I specify the following beans:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureTemplateEngine(TemplateEngine templateEngine, ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(2));
        templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("html/*"));
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

        return templateResolver;

    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver acceptHeaderResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        acceptHeaderResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return acceptHeaderResolver;

    }

}
```

So we're using the locale specified in the `Accept-Header` (or US by default if not specified), which is what I want.

However when creating the email objects before sending:

```
final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
final MimeMessageHelper message =
    new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
message.setSubject("This is my email");
message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
message.setTo(recipientEmail);
```

I'd like to be able to internationalize the email subject as well. I *could* use standard Java internationalization resource bundles but that requires me specifying a `Locale` based on the Accept-Header on the request...**so how can I access that dyamically?**

I suppose I could grab the `@RequestHeader("Accept")` in my controller/resource class and then pass it into the method that sends the email, but I'm wondering if Spring/Thymelead provide any cleaner way of accessing this value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` to get the locale defined on the current thread based on your `Accept-Header`.

More info on [LocaleContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE_to_4.3.11.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.11.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html)